# When watching a network drive "Created" is not fired when the file comes from another drive

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I have a FileWatcher that works fine on local and network drives.
On certain network drives there is a problem when the file comes from another network drive. Then the "Created" event is not fired. The UNC paths and read/write permissions are correct. I can open, edit, save, copy or delete the file with the application. 
The "changed" and "deleted" events fires when i process the file.

```
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = source;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.Filter = searchPattern;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreate);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDelete);
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChange);
```

Comment: The network drive in question is not being watched by another app/process, right? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It might be the "Renamed" event that gets fired for moved files.

Comment: @Equalsk : The Renamed event did the trick. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Renamed event did the trick. 
I am not sure if the drive is already being watched, because i am not the owner of the share. Other Shares on the same drive are firing "Created".

Many thanks